# JavaScript setTimeout does not work within for loop (manipulating DOM elements)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I'm currently working on a wordle like game, and I'm facing issues using setTimeout in a for loop when updating the background color of each letter square based on the user's guess. Without setTimeout, my code runs with the color change happening immediately before my flip animation kicks in. I'm trying to add the animation delay for the color change with setTimeout, but that causes the background colors to stop changing completely.

This is my current function for updating the display for a guess entered by the user. Any insight would be much appreciated!

```
function updateWordDisplay(rowIndex) {
    const letterRow = document.querySelectorAll('.letter-row')[rowIndex];
    const letterSquares = letterRow.querySelectorAll('.letter-square');
    const animationDuration = 500;

    for (let i = 0; i < secretWord.length; i++) {
        letterSquares[i].textContent = guessedWord[i];
        letterSquares[i].classList.add('animated');
        letterSquares[i].style.animationDelay = `${(i * animationDuration) / 2}ms`;

        const letterInstancesSecret = getLetterInstances(letterSquares[i].textContent, secretWord);
        const letterInstancesGuess = getLetterInstances(letterSquares[i].textContent, guessedWord);
        const letterPosition = getLetterPosition(letterSquares[i].textContent, guessedWord, i);

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (letterInstancesGuess > letterInstancesSecret && letterPosition > letterInstancesSecret) {
                letterSquares[i].style.backgroundColor = '#508d9c';
                console.log(letterSquares[i].style.backgroundColor);
            } else {
                if (guessedWord[i] === secretWord[i]) {
                    letterSquares[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                    console.log(letterSquares[i].style.backgroundColor);

                } else if (secretWord.includes(guessedWord[i])) {
                    letterSquares[i].style.backgroundColor = '#c034eb';
                    console.log(letterSquares[i].style.backgroundColor);

                }
            }
        }, ((i+1) * animationDuration / 2));
    }
    rowIndex++;
}
```

Comment: Why not use CSS transitions for animating style changes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I'm using a css @keyframes transition for the scaling changes, the issue is the change has to be delayed for each letter as they flip, similar to the real wordle game.

Comment: I'm probably the last holdout, but I've never played the real Wordle.

Comment: Style suggestion: Use `else if` for a series of conditions, rather than nested `else { if ... }` so you don't get deep nesting. It's easier to see that you have a bunch of mutually exclusive conditions.